Self-adjointness of generator and semigroup of an SDE
$
\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\bT}{\mathbb{T}}
\newcommand{\bP}{\mathbb{P}}
\newcommand{\bF}{\mathbb{F}}
\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\varepsilon}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newcommand{\qtext}[1]{\quad\text{#1}}
\newcommand{\qtextq}[1]{\quad\text{#1}\quad}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\trace}{tr}
$
We fix $T \in (0, \infty)$ and let $\bT$ be the interval $[0, T]$. We consider measurable functions
\begin{align}
b &: \bT \times \bR^d \to \bR^d, \\
\sigma &: \bT \times \bR^d \to \bR^d \otimes \bR^m.
\end{align}
We assume that $b$ $\sigma$ are regular enough. Let $(B_t, t \ge 0)$ be a $m$-dimensional Brownian motion and $\bF := (\cF_t, t \ge 0)$ an admissible filtration on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, \bP)$. For $(s, x) \in [0, T) \times \bR^d$, we consider the SDE
$$
\begin{cases}
\diff X^x_{s,t} & = b (t, X^x_{s, t}) \diff t + \sigma (t, X^x_{s, t}) \diff B_t
\qtextq{for} t \in [s, T] , \\
X^x_{s,s} & = x .
\end{cases}
$$
Let $a:= \sigma \sigma^\top$. The differential operator $(L_t)_{t \in \bT}$ is defined for $f \in C^2 (\bR^d)$ and $x \in \bR^d$ by
\begin{align}
L_t f (x) := \langle b (t, x), \nabla f (x) \rangle + \frac{1}{2} \trace ( a (t, x) \nabla^2 f (x) ) .
\end{align}
The semigroup $(P_{s, t})_{0 \le s < t \le T}$ is defined for $x \in {\bR}^d$ and $f \in C_b ({\bR}^d)$ by
$$
P_{s, t} f (x) := \bE [f(X^x_{s, t})] .
$$
We consider two statements:

It holds for $f, g \in C^2_c (\bR^d)$ that
$$
\int_{\bR^d} (L_t f) g \diff x = \int_{\bR^d} f (L_t g) \diff x .
$$

It holds for $f, g \in C_c (\bR^d)$ that
$$
\int_{\bR^d} (P_{s, t} f) g \diff x = \int_{\bR^d} f (P_{s, t} g) \diff x .
$$


The backward Kolmogorov equation holds, i.e., $\partial_s P_{s, t} f + L_s P_{s, t} f =0$ for $f \in C^2_b (\bR^d)$.

Is it true that (1) implies (2)?

Thank you for your elaboration.

The equation
$\int_{\mathbb{R}} d(L_t f) g , dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}} d f(L_t g) ,  dx,
$ states that the differential operator $ L_t$ is  self-adjoint with respect to the $ L^2$-inner product defined by integration over $\mathbb{R}^d $. This adjointness holds when $b$ and $ \sigma$ (and therefore $ a = \sigma \sigma^\top $) are sufficiently smooth and $ a(t,x) $ is positive definite, ensuring ellipticity.

At its core, this question seems to be a variation of this companion question. I.e., in general, (1) does not imply (2). If $[L_t ,L_{t'}]=0$, then (1) does imply (2).

Let's at least elaborate on why $P_{s,t} $ in general is not self-adjoint, even if $L_t $ is. $P_{s,t} $ can be composed from infinitesimal time evolutions,
$$
P_{s,t} = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty } \left( 1-\epsilon L_{t+N\epsilon } \right) \left( 1-\epsilon L_{t+(N-1)\epsilon } \right) \left( 1-\epsilon L_{t+(N-2)\epsilon } \right) \ldots \left( 1-\epsilon L_{t+\epsilon } \right) \ ,
$$
where $\epsilon =(s-t)/N $ has been introduced. This satisfies $\partial_{s} P_{s,t} + L_s P_{s,t} =0$, as one sees by evaluating
$$
\partial_{s} P_{s,t} = \frac{1}{\epsilon } \left( P_{s,t} - P_{s-\epsilon ,t} \right) \ .
$$
Now, consider the adjoint,
\begin{eqnarray}
P^{\dagger }_{s,t} &=& \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty } \left( 1-\epsilon L^{\dagger }_{t+\epsilon } \right) \ldots \left( 1-\epsilon L^{\dagger}_{t+(N-2)\epsilon } \right) \left( 1-\epsilon L^{\dagger}_{t+(N-1)\epsilon } \right) \left( 1-\epsilon L^{\dagger}_{t+N\epsilon } \right) \\
&=& \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty } \left( 1-\epsilon L_{t+\epsilon } \right) \ldots \left( 1-\epsilon L_{t+(N-2)\epsilon } \right) \left( 1-\epsilon L_{t+(N-1)\epsilon } \right) \left( 1-\epsilon L_{t+N\epsilon } \right)
\end{eqnarray}
using the self-adjointness of $L_t $. Thus, the ordering of the factors in $P^{\dagger }_{s,t} $ is reversed compared to $P_{s,t} $, and therefore, in general, $P^{\dagger }_{s,t} \neq P_{s,t}$. If the $L_t $ at different times commute, $[L_t ,L_{t^{\prime } }]=0$, then one can reorder the factors in $P^{\dagger }_{s,t} $, obtaining $P^{\dagger }_{s,t} = P_{s,t}$.

Can you give a specific example of such non-commuting $L_t$'s, with statement 1 satisfied but statement 2 failing to hold?

@IosifPinelis - I don't have a fully worked-out example, but if I were to go about constructing one, I'd start with something that's constant in $s$, except for a switch in behavior at a certain point, say, $L=\theta (-(t+s)/2) A + \theta((t+s)/2) B$, where the operators $A,B$ are time-independent. If we don't insist on the types of operators specified in the OP, we could use Pauli matrices, say, $A=\sigma_{x} $, $B=\sigma_{y} $ to get something that can be worked out explicitly. Insisting on the OP's form of operator, it gets messy, because we need the $\nabla^{2} $ to have it self-adjoint.
